# help me to change the word !

Tags: synonyms

(1)The extra budget is to be used to create over 110,000 jobs and help pull up economic growth by ***bolstering people's income*** with the introduction of better working conditions.

(2)The government also plans to ***expand jobs*** for senior citizens.

I wonder if I can change the word, 'bolstering,' to other words without changing the meaning of this sentence, as well as 'expand.' (synonyms)

Thank you!

Comment: have you checked a thesaurus? http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/bolstering, http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/expand

Comment: Yes but, if I use a word 'boost' instead of 'bolster,' I am not able to find any sentences and it seems a bit awkward.

Comment: boost -> boosting. That's a natural way to use *boosting*.

Comment: "pull up economic growth" is the real problem here

Comment: You could use increasing and increase in both sentences. @Xanne picked up the pull problem: No one pulls growth, they may push, encourage, or stimulate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think 'bolstering' needs to be replaced with 'rising' or 'increasing', because 'bolster' is often used to mean 'strengthen'or 'to support'. For instance, his presence bolstered my confidence. 
'To expand' means to increase in size. Here, you need a word which should mean 'increase'. It will be more appropriate if you replace 'to expand' with 'to provide increasing number of'.